# react native (type script) : Selecting the father sons check box in flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

My goal is that when user select a checkbox of one of the fathers ('Non Veg Biryanis','Pizzas','Drinks','Deserts') in the flatlist, then those sons who belong to him are also selected.
When the check box is removed from all the children belonging to the same father, then the check box is also removed for the father as well.

this is my example (but its not works as can see, the father 'Pizzas' not checked but his sons checked)
[image]

**The data is:**

```
[
    {
      title: 'Non Veg Biryanis',
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: 'chicken', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'meat', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'veg', value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },

    {
      title: 'Pizzas',
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: 'olives', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'green cheese', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'paprika', value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Drinks',
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: 'cola', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'sprite', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'orange', value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Deserts',
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: 'cake', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'ice-cream', value: false, checked: false },
        { key: 'pie', value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

**The Accordian:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, FlatList, LayoutAnimation, Platform, UIManager } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import styles from './AccordianStyle';

const Accordian = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.item);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }

  const onClick = (index: number) => {
    console.log(data);
    const temp = { ...data };
    temp.data[index].checked = !temp.data[index].checked;
    setData(temp);
  };
  const onClickFather = () => {
    const temp = { ...data };
    temp.checked = !temp.checked;
    if (temp.checked) {
      temp.data = temp.data.map((item: { checked: boolean }) => {
        item.checked = true;
      });
    }
    console.log(temp);
    setData(temp);
  };
  const toggleExpand = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onClickFather()}>
          <Icon name={'check-circle'} size={24} color={data.checked ? 'green' : '#d3d7de'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={[styles.title]}>{data.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => toggleExpand()}>
          <Icon name={expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={30} color={'grey'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.parentHr} />
      {expanded && (
        <View style={{}}>
          <FlatList
            data={data.data}
            numColumns={1}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[styles.childRow, styles.button, item.checked ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInActive]}
                  onPress={() => onClick(index)}
                >
                  <Text style={[styles.itemInActive]}>{item.key}</Text>
                  <Icon name={'check-circle'} size={24} color={item.checked ? 'green' : '#d3d7de'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.childHr} />
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Accordian;
```

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `onClick` function so that it loops through each entry in the `data` array with the [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and check if any of the children (sons) are clicked.

If one of them is, then update set the `checked` property accordingly.

```
const onClick = (index: number) => {
  setData(prevState => {
    const newData = prevState.data.map((entry, entryIndex) =>
      index === entryIndex ?
        ({ ...entry, checked: !entry.checked }) : 
        entry
    );

    const isAnyChildChecked = newData.some(({ checked }) => 
      checked === true
    );

    return ({
      ...prevState,
      checked: isAnyChildChecked,
      data: newData
    })
  });
};
```

If the parent is clicked, then check or uncheck all the children as well.

```
const onClickFather = () => {
  setData(prevState => {
    const isParentChecked = !prevState.checked;
        
    return ({
      ...prevState,
      checked: isParentChecked,
      data: prevState.data.map(item => ({ ...item, checked: isParentChecked }))
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: its not works..
its give error : 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.checked')

Comment: Ah, I see. I forgot to prepend the `prevState` variable before `data`. Please try again.

Comment: what do u mean ? can u change the code ?

Comment: I did, refresh the page. Are you sure the error is caused by my answer? Because I didn't write `item.checked`. Otherwise, if the error still occurs, then try to make a runnable example in which I can run and debug your code.

Comment: this error come from the 'onClickFather' function.
also its happen before.
can u try help me with this issue ?

Comment: can u try maybe change the 'onClickFather' function ?

Comment: I've made another edit and modified the `onClickFather` function.

Comment: its works well but now i got also worning:
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
* now i check it again and if i uncheck the father so it doesnt uncheck his sons..

Comment: Great to hear that it works. If it does, then mark the answer as accepted so that others may benefit too. Regarding your latest comment: If you do some research for that warning you'll get lot's of answers; it's a very common React warning.

Comment: but if i uncheck the father so it doesnt uncheck his sons..do u know why ?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.  Please be more specific in the future.

Comment: sorry, the meaning was that the father can check his all sons and uncheck his all sons. do u know how to fix it ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Could you verify if it works as expected?

Comment: thats works well !!